# Use mcrypt_dev_random to generate 256 bit token

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

i want to use mcrypt to create a 256 bit token to set as the cookie for the user.

I have read a number of articles suggesting to use mcrypt DEV_RANDOM

I am using the code

```
$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
```

But the result i get when i output the token is

```
ǡw��ӣ�:z���{d
```

Is this what it is supposed to look like? iF not, what do i have to do to generate a proper token.

Thanks

Comment: `mcrypt_create_iv` generates random binary data.  This is *exactly* what it's supposed to look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `bin2hex` to get a more "friendly" representation of the data. `bin2hex` will convert the bytes you have generated into an ASCII encoded hex representation of the original string.

```
$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

$hexIv = bin2hex($iv);
```

The reason you are getting the strange output is because you are taking a random sequence of bytes and trying to represent them at some kind of human readable text by treating it as a string encoded in whatever is the default encoding for the application you are viewing the string in (e.g you web browser).

Example:

```
$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

echo "RAW IV: ";
echo $iv;
echo "\n Hex: ";
echo bin2hex($iv);
```

Output:

```
RAW IV: ª£2æ|%ì­E½ßy²ý
Hex: 0aaaa332e67c25ecad45bddf7919b2fd
```

In addition you should note the following things:

- `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` will block if the entropy pool is depleted.
- `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` is most likely a better choice as it won't block. The output is less random, but this is fine for most purposes.
- An alternative function is `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` which, for your use-case, performs the same function as the two `mcrypt_` function calls (with `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM`). It does not require the `mcrypt` extension, only that PHP was compiled with OpenSSL support.

Comment: This won't work if the file was saved with BOM. We don't know how the OP's file was saved as, UTF-8 with/without BOM or just ANSI. I tested your code and WITH BOM, produced question marks. Just thought you'd like to know. My money's on the OP's file is saved WITH BOM.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This has nothing to do with files, read the question. He is trying to generate a random sequence of bytes and use it for a token in a cookie.

Comment: I find it strange though that testing your method with and without BOM produced the same result, so I'm scratching my head here LOL. I got this back when using yours `�j(R��t��*��{rnL` or is that what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: @Fred-ii- BOM is irrelevant as, again, this has zero to do with files or streams.  Please read the question! Also if you got that output you've done something wrong. I've edited my answer to include an example script that produces the raw and hex string. Additionally, even if you tried to decode the string as UTF-8 it will sill output garbage as the value of `$iv` is random bytes.